# Wrong grayscale convertion algorithm in torchvision?

Tags: python, torch, torchvision

I have the dataset of color images, that I want to convert to grayscale and use them to train my CNN. Should I use the values for all the color channels equally translated to the grayscale value, or should there be a different ratio between them?

In torchvision Grayscale the formula is: L = R * 0.2989 + G * 0.5870 + B * 0.1140.
And that are the ratios for RGB recommended by BT.601 standard based on the ideas of how human eye works.

But it seems that having different ratios for different colors is senseless if we train the neural network in grayscale: We adjust grayscale images to the eye's perception, but there is no real eye when the neural network analyzes camera sensor information.

Aren't we losing some useful data while converting color images to grayscale using color ratios and not managing them equally?

Comment: Your biggest information loss happens when transforming from color to grayscale regardless of the algorithm used to perform such conversion. Have you considered using the color images in the CNN if you are concerned about information loss? If that is not possible there are plenty of accademic papers (see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5445596 or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221501841_Spatial_Color-to-Grayscale_Transform_Preserving_Chrominance_Edge_Information) describing how to preserve as much information as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the links, have to read them. 
My idea of using grayscale here is that the images are from cctv cameras. 
Half of the time these cameras work in nightmode which is grayscale only. I need to detect events like people and opened doors on the images and most of these events happen in nightmode, i.e. are grayscaled. 
I get no significant efficacy improvements while using 3-color images, but performance/memory issues only.

Comment: Ok, I looked at your papers. Both of them seem to address the same problem: how to make two different colors with the same brightness still distinguishable on the grayscale image. Imho, no doubts that while improving 'color representation' on grayscale image they lose some brightness information. So the only application for that that I see is to make gray images better looking for the human eye. And it is still not clear why the human-eye algorithms should be a thing in the neural network training. That just looks non-optimal.

Comment: You should probably try different algorithms for color-to-grayscale conversion with the same CNN setup and see if they even make any significant difference... I'm still doubtfull any optimal solution actually exist, since some information loss is unavoidable (moving from color to grayscale) I would say that keeping information that is usefull for the human eye could be a pretty good bet for the network as well. As I said though I believe the only way to get a real answer is to test it